Deriving how angular momentum is the generator of rotations
I'm trying to demonstrate the following identity:
$$R_z(\theta) = e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} L_z\theta}$$
I know the more general relation has $J_z$ and not $L_z$, but I'm only interested in showing it for the latter. If I write down Schrödinger's equation:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = H\Psi$$
it is clear I can pass the term $i\hbar$ to the right hand side of the equation, and it is also quite clear the solution can be expressed by exponentiating the right hand side:
$$\Psi = e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} H t}\Psi_0$$
where $U=e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar} H t}$ is the time evolution unitary operator. Let us now recall that $L_z=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ , so we can write the equation:
$$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\pmb{+}i}{\hbar}L_z\Psi$$
Essentially, this is just another Schrödinger equation, where instead of time evolution we now have a rotation. Proceeding as before, the solution can be written as the matrix resulting from exponentiating the right hand side acting on some initial state $\Psi_0$:
$$\Psi = e^{\frac{\pmb{+}i}{\hbar} L_z\theta}\Psi_0$$
therefore, the rotation operator I get has the opposite sign compared to the one I should be getting. Why is this? I' thinking maybe by writing the problem this way I'm performing a rotation around the $-z$ axis instead of the $z$ axis, which would explain the $+$ sign I'm getting instead of the $-$ sign I should be getting. However, since I'm taking the derivative with respect to positive $\theta$ (that is to say, how my wavefunction evolves as I rotate it anticlockwise, which corresponds to the $+z$ direction), I would expect to get the corresponding negative sign in the exponent.

It's the difference between an active and passive rotation - i.e., are you rotating the wave function or your coordinate system?
In solving your Schrödinger-like equation, you are asking how $\psi$ changes when $\theta$ is varied - this corresponds to the passive point of view, where you rotate your coordinate system.
In contrast, $R(\theta) = e^{-i J_z \theta}$ is how the rotation operator looks from the active point of view, where you rotate the wave function, but keep your coordinates fixed.

Thanks for your answer! Is there a concise definition for active and passive rotations? I've never really heard of it before. Anyhow, the moment I write down my problem, it's just a mathematical one. Shouldn't I be able to solve it without using these concepts?

You can find a lot of information on active vs passive transformations on YouTube, or on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation). If you want a discussion specifically within the context of quantum mecahnics, I think there is one in Ballentine's book

The definition of the rotation operator depends on whether you take the active or passive viewpoint. In the passive viewpoint, the rotation operator would be $R(\theta) = e^{i J_z \theta}$, which is exactly what you arrive at.
